# Problem in passing arguments between functions iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my application I have location function:

```
- (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location {    
  lati = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%f", location.coordinate.latitude] ;
  longi = [[NSString alloc ]initWithFormat:@"%f", location.coordinate.longitude ];    
  [self ParseXML_of_Google_PlacesAPI:googleUrl];
}
```

...and I have another function to which I want to pass lati and longi:

```
-(void)ParseXML_of_Google_PlacesAPI:(NSString *)_googleUrl { 
  //use lati and longi in this line 
  googleUrl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=%f,%f&radius=500&name=asda&sensor=false&key=mykey",lati,longi];
  NSURL *googlePlacesURL = [NSURL  URLWithString:googleUrl ];
  NSData *xmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:googlePlacesURL];
  xmlDocument = [[GDataXMLDocument alloc]initWithData:xmlData options:0 error:nil];
  NSArray *arr = [xmlDocument.rootElement elementsForName:@"result"];
  placesOutputArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
  for(GDataXMLElement *e in arr ){        
          [placesOutputArray addObject:e];
  }
}
```

How can I do that? I just need the values of `lati` and `longi` in the `ParseXML_of_Googe_PlacesApi:` method. Everything else is working fine

Comment: You pass the argument `_googleUrl` for `ParseXML_of_Google_PlacesAPI:` but you don't use it in the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify the ParseXML_of_Google_PlacesAPI:(NSString *)_googleUrl method to take other arguments:

i.e )ParseXML_of_Google_PlacesAPI:(NSString *)_googleUrl long:(float) longitude lat:(float) latitude

You can use float if they floats or replace the float with NSString if they are nsstrings like in your method.

You can then use the nsstringformat to reformat your URL.

Answer (score 3):

Change your declaration to:

```
-(void)ParseXML_of_Google_PlacesAPI:(NSString *)_googleUrl withLat:(NSString*)lati andLong:(NSString*)longi {
```

Then change your calling code:

```
[self ParseXML_of_Google_PlacesAPI:googleUrl withLat:lati andLong:longi];
```

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite your method as

```
- (void)parseXMLOfGooglePlacesAPI:(NSString *)url latitude:(NSString *)latitude longitude:(NSString *)longitude;
```

and then call it as

```
[self parseXMLOfGooglePlacesAPI:googleURL latitude:late longitude:longi];
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to rewrite the method or you need to use the variables in more than one method,  make `lati` and `longi` properties of the class this code appears in.

In the `.h` file you would define:

```
@property(nonAtomic, retain) NSString *lati;
@property(nonAtomic, retain) NSString *longi;
```

.. and in the `.m` file you would:

```
@synthesize lati, longi;
```

Then you would use them like:

```
- (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location {
  self.lati = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%f", location.coordinate.latitude] ;
  self.longi = [[NSString alloc ]initWithFormat:@"%f", location.coordinate.longitude ];    
  [self ParseXML_of_Google_PlacesAPI:googleUrl];
}
```

... and:

```
-(void)ParseXML_of_Google_PlacesAPI:(NSString *)_googleUrl {  
  googleUrl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=%f,%f&radius=500&name=asda&sensor=false&key=mykey",self.lati,self.longi];
  NSURL *googlePlacesURL = [NSURL  URLWithString:googleUrl ];
  NSData *xmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:googlePlacesURL];
  xmlDocument = [[GDataXMLDocument alloc]initWithData:xmlData options:0 error:nil];
  NSArray *arr = [xmlDocument.rootElement elementsForName:@"result"];
  placesOutputArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
  for(GDataXMLElement *e in arr ){        
          [placesOutputArray addObject:e];
  }
}
```